# Nativescript not accepting https

Tags: nativescript

I'm really struggling to get nativescript to work in the office. That's because of SSL.
The main problem is that the webview does not load any https resources. I tried to open the resources on android chrome it said something along the lines 'connection may not be private/save, certificate cannot be trusted'. I asked an he told me that they have some sort of man in the middle which kinda acts like a virus scanner. We installed a certificate on the device and requesting https resources in Chrome worked fine. Unfortunately it did not work fine in nativescript. It still does not load https resources. I also tried http ones and they work fine.

How do I solve that problem? Why is nativescript still not happy with https even though chrome is?

Can I not just ignore SSL? In node you can do `npm set strict-ssl false?` for example.

Answer (score 0):

`Google Chrome !== WebView` In Android, you have to handle the SSL errors yourself within the WebView. You can't compare it with Chrome as it's a fully qualified browser in other hand WebView is a simple component.

[Here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/webview-bypass-ssl-error/3313/4?u=manojdcoder) is how you can extend the WebView to handle SSL errors. If you still have issues, please share the website you are trying to hit.